# How to get rid of horizontal width of 100% on angular material chips?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm working on an Angular material project and ran into an issue. I'm trying to use vertically stacked chips, but when I use the predefined code the width of the chips is 100%. Is there a way to unset the width value in the mat-chip-list-stacked class? I don't want the chips to be full horizontal width.

```
<mat-chip-list class="mat-chip-list-stacked" aria-orientation="vertical">
  <mat-chip>Papadum</mat-chip>
  <mat-chip>Naan</mat-chip>
  <mat-chip>Dal</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

This is what the code looks like:

[image]

This is what I want the code to look like:

[image]

Comment: How much width you want?. like 10% 20% etc...

Comment: @GangadharGandi - I updated the message content to show I was looking for a dynamic width.

Comment: Updated the answer with new styles. Please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Unset the width, we can go with the below css.

```
.mat-chip-list .mat-chip {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the best solution:

```
mat-chip {
  max-width: max-content;
  max-width: intrinsic;           /* Safari/WebKit uses a non-standard name */
  max-width: -moz-max-content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular 9, you can overwrite the `mat-chip` component styles. You could either set max-width to be of a certain length,

```
mat-chip {
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

Or, overwrite the width using the `!important` declaration:

```
mat-chip {
  width: 50px!important;
}
```

If you are using anything before Angular 9, you will have to class properties by selecting the right CSS classes.

```
.mat-chip-list .mat-chip {
  width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I updated the message content to show I was looking for a dynamic width.

Comment: @user3767997 how are the widths set? Will you be providing the length of the widths

Comment: No they're being set automatically by the class="mat-chip-list-stacked" which is predefined by material.